# Jupyter notebook failed to adapt to default browser

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook

I installed Jupiter notebook as part of Anaconda3. I changed to the default browser form Chrome to Safari, however, it still runs form Chrome.

To explicitly set the required browser, I created a configuration file as follow:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and changed this line in the config file from:

```
# c.NotebookApp.browser = ''
```

to

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '~/Applications/Safari.app'
```

I get the below error:

> No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.

How can I get Jupiter notebook to detect the default browser without explicitly configure it? If that is not possible, how to get it to work with different browser?

I am on Mac OS V. 10.12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now able to run it on Safari by set the configuration file to have:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'open -a /Applications/Safari.app %s'
```

Still not sure why Jupiter doesn't recognise the default browser when configured to `c.NotebookApp.browser = ''`